# How to format a chain of equations using vertical arrows?

Tags: equations, arrows

Basically, what I want to do is something like

[image]

where each equation is separated by a space containing a single or double vertical arrow slightly to the left.

However, if there is a another preferred way of doing it, I would appreciate a heads-up. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.sx](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)!

Comment: While you can do this, I would not regard it as good style, often it leads to long unreadable lists.  Best is adding explanation between the equations (note in this particular case there is a condition on m for the biimplication to be true).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`mathtools` provides

```
\ArrowBetweenLines[〈symbol〉 ]
\ArrowBetweenLines*[ 〈symbol〉 ]    %% symbol on right side.
```

`<symbol>` can be any arrow symbol.

Code:

```
 \documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
    && y&=mx+b\\
    \ArrowBetweenLines%
    && x&=\frac{y-b}{m}
    \end{alignat*}
    \begin{alignat}{2}
    && y&=mx+b\\
    \ArrowBetweenLines%
    && x&=\frac{y-b}{m}
\end{alignat}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
     y&=mx+b  &&\\
    \ArrowBetweenLines*[\downarrow]%
    x&=\frac{y-b}{m} &&
    \end{alignat*}
    \begin{alignat}{2}
    y&=mx+b  &&\\
    \ArrowBetweenLines*[\uparrow]%
    x&=\frac{y-b}{m}  &&
\end{alignat}
\end{document}
```

[image]

For details, see `mathtools` manual, page 21, section 3.4.6.

Answer (score 3):

Just search for some arrow that you like (I am using `\Updownarrow` which needs no packages at all) and add it in an extra line of the `align` environment. In order to get it on the left side, just add a `\quad` or `\quadd` in front of the `&`-separator.

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{align*}
    y&=mx+b\\
    \Updownarrow\quad&\\
    x&=\frac{y-b}{m}
    \end{align*}
    \begin{align}
    y&=mx+b\\
    \Updownarrow\quad&\notag\\
    x&=\frac{y-b}{m}
\end{align}     
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

As you asked for other ways to do that -- I would use one of the two following versions:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\[y=mx+b \quad\Rightarrow\quad x=\frac{y-b}{m}\] 

\begin{align*}
y&=mx+b \shortintertext{which can be transformed to:}
x&=\frac{y-b}{m}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```